# Calling OAuth mechanism for Azure DevOps through ajax or some other means like [Authorize] attribute

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, oauth, azure-devops

I'm trying to create work-item in Azure DevOps programmatically using OAuth as a mechanism for authentication. The users will have an input form which will have input texts, dropdowns etc. for writing description, selecting Assigned To, etc. will I will fetch and use that to associate respective fields in Azure DevOps and create a workitem in the name of user.
I referred this code https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample/OAuthWebSample/ for implementing OAuth.

Now this code provided in github works fine as an individual. However I'm having some difficulties to combine it with my code.

**At first, I'm writing the straightforward code taken from github which works fine and then I'll write my code which I want to integrate with the former one**

This is **the straightforward code** where I just have a button in the UI(say Authorize button), which upon clicking calls the Authorize ActionResult in OAuth controller.
Here's the code:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Guid, TokenModel> s_authorizationRequests = new Dictionary<Guid, TokenModel>();
public ActionResult Authorize()
{
     Guid state = Guid.NewGuid();

     s_authorizationRequests[state] = new TokenModel() { IsPending = true };

     return new RedirectResult(GetAuthorizationUrl(state.ToString()));
}
```

TokenModel is the class used to deserialize the Json afterwards. From here, it calls the GetAuthorizationUrl method and builds the URI.

```
private static String GetAuthorizationUrl(String state)
        {
            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthUrl"]);
            var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query ?? String.Empty);

            queryParams["client_id"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientAppId"];
            queryParams["response_type"] = "Assertion";
            queryParams["state"] = state;
            queryParams["scope"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Scope"];
            queryParams["redirect_uri"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CallbackUrl"];

            uriBuilder.Query = queryParams.ToString();

            return uriBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

It then automatically redirects to Callback method which is my CallbackUrl with authorization code if the user has accepted the Terms and conditions and generates an accesstoken which is then just passed into a View.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Callback(String code, Guid state)
        {
            String error;
            if (ValidateCallbackValues(code, state.ToString(), out error))
            {
                // Exchange the auth code for an access token and refresh token
                HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenUrl"]);
                requestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                Dictionary<String, String> form = new Dictionary<String, String>()
                {
                    { "client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer" },
                    { "client_assertion", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientAppSecret"] },
                    { "grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" },
                    { "assertion", code },
                    { "redirect_uri", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CallbackUrl"] }
                };
                requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(form);

                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await s_httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    String body = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    TokenModel tokenModel = s_authorizationRequests[state];
                    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(body, tokenModel);
                    //ViewBag.DeliverableId = WorkItemsHelper.CreateWorkItem(tokenModel.AccessToken);
                    ViewBag.Token = tokenModel;
                }
                else
                {
                    error = responseMessage.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            {
                ViewBag.Error = error;
            }

            ViewBag.ProfileUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProfileUrl"];

            return View("TokenView");
        }
```

**This thing works fine till now. But now what I want to achieve and what I've tried is as follows**
Now I want to achieve this through my input form, like this(there will be other fields)

```
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label> Title </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label> Description </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description"/>
      </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

When the user clicks on Save button, I want the accesstoken to be generated as well as use that accesstoken and the input fields from the user and create a workitem in azure devops. 
At first, I tried ajax calling in which I was calling Authorize method on click save button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testbutton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Oauth/Authorize",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    document.getElementById("returnedmessage").innerHTML = response;
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('an error occured');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

(I wanted to return Json(ViewBag.TokenModel.AccessToken) from the Callback method)
So this button hits the Authorize method, but after that instead of going to the Callback method, it returns response with some html and I've errors in my browser console saying 404 not found.

**The second approach** I tried to follow on clicking on Save button, I'll call a method(say Index), and try to call Authorize method inside it,

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
     var s = Authorize();
     return View();
}
```

But still it doesn't hit the CallBack method and nothing happens.

Is there anyway that I can achieve my task of generating accesstoken simultaneously and use it to create workitem by calling my method with the user inputs?

**Note: I want to avoid another button which explicitly generates accesstoken and after that go to my input page with accesstoken as hidden field or in cookies**

Is there any way that I can make Custom defined attribute like the Authorize attribute which when used on top of controller, they authenticate the users before accessing any methods? Or any other workaround?

Apologies for the long question or if I wasn't clear enough. Any help in little bit details will be gladly appreciated.